# Committing a transaction with Play Framework

Tags: jpa, transactions, playframework

I have a long running process (video rendering) in which occasional updates are made to the database to indicate the progress. However, how can I do this without locking the database for other processes. I tried to use the @NoTransaction annotation, but now there don't seem to be any updates to the database.

Is there a way to, in such a long process, just create a transaction when needed?
I.e. search for the object and maintain it in a variable and then open a transaction, make the change, save it, and close the transaction so it is committed to the database. (there might be a need for a refresh in there, but that is fine).

Any suggestions? I can only find the Rollback feature in the Play! Documentation.

Comment: If you job can be split into chunks, extract the work into a method which you annotate with @Transactional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Play 1.2.4, please check the documentation on [jobs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jobs). That should work for your task.

If you are using Play 2.0, you may want to check the Asynchronous programming part in [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaAsync).

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the process is very long, and as soon as the first change is made to keep track of the progress the database is locked. I now have a Job() to update the status so it is in a different transaction